# Sistema de transferência ( opções)

Tags: java

Boa tarde!

Pessoal, sou iniciante e queria saber como faço pra simular uma transferência de Banco (Conta + Conta2), sendo "Conta2" uma classe criada fora da Classe "Conta".

Fiz o os métodos Sacar e Depositar dentro da Classe "Conta".

Meu código tá assim:

```
public class Conta {

String nome; String numero; double saldo;

public void Depositar(double NovoValor) {

if (NovoValor > 0) this.saldo = this.saldo + NovoValor; }

public void Sacar(double NovoSaque) {

if (this.saldo > NovoSaque) this.saldo = this.saldo - NovoSaque;

}

}
```

Comment: Como você está começando vou perguntar antes de dar minha resposta, tu já chegou a ler sobre métodos estáticos?

Comment: Ainda não, tô no 1° da facul, isso é um exercício e foi até aonde eu conseguir chegar com oque conheço até agora.

Answer (score 0):

Você deve fazer uma função para realizar a transferência que terá como parâmetros: a conta destino e o valor, essa função vai chamar as duas outras funções que você já fez afinal, se pudermos reutilizar o código é melhor.

```
public void transferir(Conta destino, double valor){
    destino.Depositar(valor);
    this.Sacar(valor);
}
```